# What does “had been a rusty sea shanty” and "urban" mean in the following content?

Tags: meaning

> The Beatles sang “held her hand in mine” they harmonized like Top Cat
>   and his gang, cartoon-like and feline in their ease and mobility. Love
>   Me Do had been a rusty sea shanty – album one, track one was young and
>   entirely urban.

Comment: If you understand what [*sea shanty*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSea_shanty&ei=y7SeVb6MMNCAygSgp4fwBg&usg=AFQjCNHnKWzT6PKnIjjxt3w5UMW653VExg&sig2=ZSbMD9LEnAzf6hrpMTGm0g&bvm=bv.96952980,d.aWw), [*rusty*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rusty) (probably definition 4) and [*urban*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urban) mean, then you're doing just as well as any of us native English speakers in understanding this.

Comment: That is exceedingly poor writing.

Comment: Lennon and McCartney themselves struggled with the lyric of I Saw Her Standing There ["Well, she was just seventeen / You know what I mean ..."].  Good rock 'n roll song, all the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanings of the terms:

- A 'sea shanty' is a traditional sung sung by sailors, typically simple and easy to sing.
- 'Rusty' means what it says, but also implies 'old' or 'decayed'
- 'Urban' means of or pertaining to a town or city, and applied to the arts usually means "sophisticated" (at least it did in the sixties when this piece was written).

My interpretation of this is that the writer thinks that "Love me Do' (the Beatles first single) was a simple traditional song, archaic in style. By contrast he thinks that "Saw her standing there" (the first track from the Beatles first album, which came after "Love Me Do" and contains the lines "held her hand in mine") has a style that is young and sophisticated.